# Can .onion website owner see visitor IP address connecting using TOR network?

Tags: ip-address, website

i have installed `TOR` on my `cent OS 7 x64`. 
and using it for browsing `.onion` sites.

i would like to know , Can `.onion` website owner see `visitor IP` address connecting using `TOR network` ?

i am asking this, because i would like to know is there any way , can `.onion` website owner block specific `IP address` from accessing `.onion` website ?

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working as intended, then NO, the .onion website owner Cannot see a visitor IP address. Most leaks, such as from insecure plugins would be unable to reveal your IP to a .onion site either, as they would involve sending traffic over clearnet which is unable to reach a .onion site. There are some situations where bittorrent traffic, which shouldn't be used over tor anyway, can send out your regular clearnet IP over tor so there is always some extremely small chance a bad enough combination of plug-ins and/or exploits could somehow leak your IP to a .onion site but it's extremely unlikely and probably not a concern if you're just worried about being banned. You could always just resolve the security issue if you do get banned, therefore circumventing the ban.

If you're very concerned about IP leaks, Whonix attempts to prevent many ways your IP can leak with other Tor implementations. You run a customized Torbrowser bundle in a Linux Virtual Machine on an isolated network that can only connect to a second Linux VM whose sole job is to ensure all traffic goes over Tor. It's fairly easy to setup as you can just drop pre-built appliances into VirtualBox or KVM. 
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main_Page
https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whonix

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the interaction details - but theoretically yes, it's possible. For example if you're using an add-on in browser for a website or running an external component as a separate executable(hello, Flash!). But in almost all cases - no, it's impossible.